# Default approach to a http client with c++

Tags: c++, rest, oauth-2.0, httpclient

looking at how high level languages, like Java, C# and Python handle http requests as a client, I'm wondering what the default approach is in c++ today.

My **requirements** are:

- HTTP Client for a REST Interface
- HTTP over SSL
- Support of OAuth2 Client credentials

The OAuth2 support I scratched very fast and accepted, that this needs to implemented.

I found a number of libraries, but most of them appear to be rather outdated and a bit "unprofessional".

So here is a list of what I could find and what my thoughts are about these:

**libcurl**

While this appears to be the most professional choice. The C API is a bummer and of course the OAuth support does not exist. But this seems to be the optimal choice for me right now.

**CPR**

A c++ wrapper for libcurl and it appears to be a rather badly maintained library, which is a nono. It appears to have https support, but in the github md it says it hasnt.

**curlpp**

This project appears to be not maintained anymore.

**boost::asio**

If I am not mistaken, I have to do everythings myself here. I am trying to get sth. done and don't want to reinvent the wheel.

**Qt**

While it doesn't look bad, I'm kind of reluctant towards using a UI framework for communication. But maybe I'm mistaken.

**cpprestsdk**

While looking good for my purpose at first, OAuth2 client credentials are not supported. The whole OAuth2 part is flagged as experimental. And thats the case for a few years now. Seems to be unfinished and badly maintained.

**Conclusions**

So probably c++ isn't the usual language you do http client stuff in, but this is such a basic thing, that I'm suprised about the libraries that are out there.

Did I miss anything big?

What is the default approach at this? Is there a better "high level" choice. Or is the default approach doing it low level boost::asio style for optimal performance?

Comment: This feels like a recommend libraries question in disguise, but it could be just me misreading it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wasn't aware that it is not allowed to do that. On the other hand I would have been happy to see a question regarding this topic.

Comment: It's pretty easy to build a small C++ wrapper around `libcurl` if you know what you need to do. I made one very simple base class that is easy to build upon (@[github](https://github.com/TedLyngmo/curl-Easy-cpp)) but I don't know enough about `OAuth2` to add support for it. `libcurl` does support it somehow though. At least it has a `CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you skipped most common libraries like [crow](https://github.com/ipkn/crow) for a small projects and fast pace development. It's quite limited however provides enough functionality.

The [Poco Project](https://pocoproject.org/) which is the most mature library I came across and provides a lot of functionality for mature projects.

Comment: I definitely forgot about poco. I stumpled upon it before. While it looks well maintained and it would absolutely suffice, it seems a bit large to "just implement a http client", but you got a point. From a "getting things done" perspective this would be a great fit.